# Make localhost/ call a controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using codeigniter and am using an `.htaccess` to rewrite `localhost/index.php/some_class` as `localhost/some_class`.

How can i have `localhost/` itself call a certain controller? as in localhost will be a class and `localhost/some_func` would be possible.

#### EDIT:

This is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I think you should better do it within the codeigniter framework than within the .htaccess file. A basic setup in the .htaccess is enough, the rest you can configure in your application.

Answer (score 3):

You want to to edit application/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "some_class";
```

By changing the default_controller, this will call the index function of some_class. You will not be able to call localhost/my_function where my_function belongs to some_class using this method.

Edit:

I misread your post, you want to edit your htaccess file to redirect everything to some_class. If you post your .htaccess we can help you out.

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/some_class/$1 [L]
```

Note: This sort of goes against the MVC structure.

Comment: These rewrite rules don't look very sane. I'd would suggest to remove the `RewriteCond` and just do a `RewriteRule ^$ index.php/some_class [L]` instead to not introduce needless problems.

Comment: Thanks, so the upper part of your answer is not relevant to my situation but the edit is?

Comment: Agreed, I was just providing a quick example from a google search.. Mainly just highlighting the /index.php/some_class/$1 aspect.

Comment: @Eddie, What dir would i place this controller in? and would it bee named index.php?

Comment: Read this:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Learn how to create controllers before continuing.

Comment: @Eddie, I have read it but still don't know where to place the controller and what to name it.

Comment: Name it what you wish, just make sure it's the same as the controller class name... then put the file in application/controllers/ .. Everything you need to know is on that link.

Comment: @Eddit i have all these things in place and know what you're talking about, but still no use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to define a default controller that will execute its index function when you call localhost/

but, you can also do the other thing you were thinking, to catch directly with a method of that controller without the controller name

```
localhost/some_func
```

you need to use wildcards in routes, [here is how](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)